How does the parent component re-execute a function after a Svelte child component changes?
I have a svelte code.I want to implement a function that the parent component re-executes after the child component is updated.
I am facing a problem now.After the child component is updated, the parent component function is re-triggered, but it will enter an infinite loop.
parent component
<script lang="ts">
  import { Button } from "$lib/components/ui/button";
  import { SquarePlus } from "lucide-svelte";
  import Datatable from "$lib/components/datatable/datatable.svelte";
  import { getUserListAPI } from "@/apis/hook";
  import type { User, UserFilter } from "@/interfaces/user";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  let data: User[] = [];
  let dataSize = 0;
  
  let tableFilterDetail:UserFilter = {
    pageIndex:1,
    pageLimit:10
  }
  const getData = async (req:UserFilter) => {
    //AXIOS post get remote data
    const res = await getUserListAPI(req);
    data = res.data.rows;
    dataSize = res.data.count;
  };
  onMount(()=>{
    getData(tableFilterDetail)
  })
  $:{
    getData(tableFilterDetail)
  }
</script>

<div>
  <div class="mb-2 w-full flex justify-between items-center">
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight">User</h2>
    <div class="flex items-center">
      <Button
        variant="success"
        class="ml-1 h-10 w-28 flex items-center justify-center rounded-lg "
      >
        <SquarePlus size="16" />New
      </Button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <Datatable {data} {columns} {dataSize} bind:tableFilterDetail/>
</div>

child component
<script lang="ts">
......

  //update state and update tableAttr
  $: {
    datatableAttr.update((state) => ({
      ...state,
      hiddenColumn: hideForId,
    }));
    datatableAttr.update((state) => ({
      ...state,
      dataSize: dataSize,
    }));
    datatableAttr.update((state) => ({
      ...state,
      pageSize: pageSize,
    }));
    tableFilterDetail = {
      pageIndex: $datatableAttr.currentPage,
      pageLimit: $datatableAttr.pageSize.value,
    };
    tableData.set(data);
  }

</script>
......
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
      <label for="itemsPerPage" class="text-gray-700">Page shows:</label>
      <Select.Root portal={null} bind:selected={pageSize}>
        <Select.Trigger class="w-[130px]">
          <Select.Value />
        </Select.Trigger>
        <Select.Content>
          <Select.Group>
            {#each tableSize as size}
              <Select.Item value={size.value} label={size.label}
                >{size.label}</Select.Item
              >
            {/each}
          </Select.Group>
        </Select.Content>
        <Select.Input name="" />
      </Select.Root>
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
      <Pagination.Root
        count={$datatableAttr.dataSize}
        perPage={$datatableAttr.pageSize.value}
        let:pages
        let:currentPage
        bind:page={$datatableAttr.currentPage}
      >
        <Pagination.Content>
          <Pagination.Item>
            <Pagination.PrevButton />
          </Pagination.Item>
          {#each pages as page (page.key)}
            {#if page.type === "ellipsis"}
              <Pagination.Item>
                <Pagination.Ellipsis />
              </Pagination.Item>
            {:else}
              <Pagination.Item>
                <Pagination.Link {page} isActive={currentPage == page.value}>
                  {page.value}
                </Pagination.Link>
              </Pagination.Item>
            {/if}
          {/each}
          <Pagination.Item>
            <Pagination.NextButton />
          </Pagination.Item>
        </Pagination.Content>
      </Pagination.Root>
    </div>
......

It can be realized that the API is requested when the component is first loaded, and the API is requested again and the table data is updated when the table data changes.It won't enter an infinite loop.

please explain what you're actually trying to achieve here: why do you think you need this to happen? (i.e. what functionality are you trying achieve that makes you think the parent needs to rerun code after a child updates?)

I will ask the API after loading a page. The required data will be displayed to the data table.
Datatable has a table, paging, search box and display quantity each page.
Display values ​​per page. When the paging and search boxes are changed, the API request will be re -triggered.
In order to ensure the reuse of DataTable, I encapsulated it as a component. This data table component can also be used on other pages.

Okay but then the parent would be the owner of the data, wouldn't it? It gets the data, then sends that on to the children for rendering. There is no reason for the children to trigger anything in the parent, it already has all the information.

Yes, I also encountered the problem of an infinite loop. That is, monitoring the changes of child components in the parent component. $:{
getData(tableFilterDetail)
}
tableFilterDetail is bidirectionally bound to the child component. tableFilterDetail is the paging, search box and other attributes in the child component.

That large reactive $: {} statement in your child will re-run anytime anything within the curly braces changes, the data, the store, the filter, the state etc. So as soon as it hits it will be in a loop cause the filter is there
I would suggest removing any references to tableFilterDetail in the reactive statement because right now when data changes, it updates that filter, and when that filter changes, it updates data...
// update store and tableData when ONLY the data variable changes
$: data && updateStore()
const updateStore = () => {
    datatableAttr.update((state) => ({
        ...state,
        hiddenColumn: hideForId,
        dataSize: dataSize,
        pageSize: pageSize,
    }));
    tableData.set(data);
}
//  find some other way to update the tableFilterDetail when the filter changes

For updating the filter after removing it
Is there a reason the perPage={$datatableAttr.pageSize.value} and (currentPage) in the Pagination has to be from the dataTableAttr store? Could it not just be bound to the incomming tableFilterDetail.pageLimit instead?
That would just push the filter back and forth without having to use the store if so.
bind:perPage={tableFilterDetail.pageLimit}
bind:currentPage={tableFilterDetail.pageIndex}


Your solution solved my problem, thank you for your help.

Oh great! No problem
